# SSRS Report with Parameters Not Showing Full Data, but Parameters showing in Filter

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder

I have a report that I created with Microsoft Report Builder that uses parameters for a list of names. The report is sent out on a subscription basis with each user getting the report filtered down to their name only. In the main (unfiltered) report, not all the users are showing up. However, I do see the users in the drop down filter parameter box. When I select a user that is not showing up on the main report and filter down to them specifically, their rows of data show up. My query is correct since I see the data in there. The individual filtered version of the report is correct, since all the users are showing up in the drop down. The main report seems to be truncated in some way since all the users are not showing up.

Example:

**Full Report**

```
Parameter Filter: Person A, Person B, Person C

Date         Name
2020-07-30   Person A
2020-07-30   Person B
```

Person C shows up in the filter, but not in the full report. When I filter JUST to Person C, their row shows up, example below.

**Filtered Report**

```
Parameter Filter: Person C

Date         Name
2020-07-30   Person C
```

Any assistance or guidance to display everyone in the unfiltered report would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Would you please also show your `WHERE` clause or wherever you are applying the parameter to the query? And what kind of DB are you connecting to, is it SQL Server?

Comment: are you using a stored procedure for your dataset? If so, check the length of your parameter.

Comment: I am using a Stored Procedure, and it is connecting to Microsoft SQL Server.

Thank you @Harry! I changed the declared variable to `NVARCHAR(MAX)` and that resolved it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment.. since it solved the issue.

Change the parameter declaration on your SQL stored procedure to be big enough to accomodate all the values for your parameter.

E.G - NVARCHAR(MAX)